# StackApp site content copied on other public sites

Tags: discussion, legal, stackapps, copyright-infringement

I am using Google Analytics to track the number of visitors coming on my page everyday. Yesterday, I happen to see the referrals and I saw [this page](http://data.yodase.com/questions/a8fa08265dba48859cc47d6fed682650)

This is a public website and when I visited it, I saw it has exact contents which I put on [Stackapps Page: StackEye Chrome Extension to follow users and questions](https://stackapps.com/q/4454/20686)

I thought this is not legal but how is it possible that people are copying the content without any kind of attribution.

Is this right ?

How can we prevent people from copying the content on their own website ?